# Removing styling from a table inside a table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm currently trying to use an HTML table with an HTML table, and I'm using the following CSS style for the outside table:

```css
table.jobtable tr:nth-child(4n+1) 
{
background-color: #65594D;
}
table.jobtable tr:nth-child(4n+3) 
{
background-color: #3E362F;
}
```

I want to be able to make a table inside one of the rows without adopting it's background color. However, everything I seem to try results in the background color being adopted. Seems like such a trivial thing to be stuck on.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasey:

```
table table {
    background: none; /* Or whatever background you want */
}
```

Comment: You mean `table.jobtable table`? (As otherwise it would apply to any set of nested tables.)

Comment: Simplest posible example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the > selector in css.

```css
table.jobtable > tr:nth-child(4n+1) 
{
background-color: #65594D;
}
```

This will only apply the style to tr elements that are direct children of table.jobtable, so it won't cascade down to the next table. [If you use a tbody tag, you'll need to do table.jobtable > tbody > tr:nth-child(4n+1).]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're specifically setting the background color of the inner table (as I don't know of a CSS property value that will cause the selected elements to inherit the property's value from an element that is not the closest element in the chain that has the property set to a specific value) and you've already tried selecting the nested table as a child of the outer table (as per 3rror404's answer), you probably need to increase the specificity of the selector for the inner table.

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Here's the specificity calculations for CSS2.1 if you're working with an older browser: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#specificity